# iTextSharp read PDF with AES Encryption throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm trying to open a PDF with itextsharp that was encrypted with AES 256 and display it.  The PDF was encrypted with itextsharp as well.  I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.0.0.  This code works if the encryption is set to 'standard encryption'.

An exception is thrown on the closing bracket of the inner 'using': Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/pdf/foo.pdf");
string password = "openSesame";

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline");
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)))
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream))
    {
    }

    Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.GetBuffer());
}

Response.End();
```

Update (forgot encryption code):

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(fileStream);
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    copy.SetEncryption(bytes, bytes, 0, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);

    // add some documents with 'copy.AddDocument()';

    copy.Close();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: could you add your `copy` initialization code?

Comment: Added.  You got me thinking...  I wonder if it is something in the PdfCopyFields (which is obsolete)...  I was having issues with PdfCopy  so I needed to use PdfCopyFields, can't remember why right now.  I will try my code with PdfCopy.

Comment: I have confirmed that the same exception is thrown if PdfCopy is used instead of PdfCopyFields.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick sample I put together that works to encrypt a PDF with 256-bit AES encryption:

```
var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openDialog.DefaultExt = "pdf";
if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    using (var input = openDialog.OpenFile())
    {
        var saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveDialog.DefaultExt = "pdf";
        if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(input)) 
            {
                using (var output = saveDialog.OpenFile())
                {
                    PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(
                        reader, output,
                        PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256,
                        "password", "password",
                        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```